# Can "bed wetting" be said: 'pee your bed' or 'pee in your bed'

Tags: word-usage, prepositions

Kids wet their beds. So can't it be:

> He peed his bed.

Or

> He peed in his bed.

What sounds right:#1 or #2? It occurred to me because it's said 'he peed his pants.'

Comment: Can someone answer it?

Comment: I'm quite sure there's a typo in the title of your question and you had meant to say ***bed*** *wetting*, not ***bet*** *wetting*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's my opinion: without the preposition "in", it needs to be an accident and a place where a pee-accident would commonly happen.

> "He peed his pants." "He peed his shorts."  "He peed himself." "He peed on himself." "He peed his bed." "He peed in his bed"

All sound OK.

> "The poor man was incontinent and accidentally peed his wife's knitting."  -- **No**

S/B: "... peed *on* the knitting."

> "Benny, did you pee my shoes again? You bad dog!" -- **No**

S/B: "... peed *in*, or *on*, the shoes."

The word "peed" is so informal, in *some* situations it's not even polite to say it. So if you are using it, as long as people can understand you, they probably won't take offense at your prepositions.

Comment: So the ones you marked with : No ,.                                     Can't they be used? @Lorel C."The poor man was incontinent and accidentally peed his wife's knitting." -- No.                                                                            Benny, did you pee my shoes again? You bad dog!" -- No

Comment: So can't "prepositions" be dropped in your example sentences too? @Lorel C.

Comment: And can't it be:he peed in his pants.

Comment: @It'saboutEnglish , I *think* it's ok to say "in" with "pants", but it sounds more common without the "in". I'm not sure on that one.

Comment: @It'saboutEnglish,  Myself, I think they ("knitting" and "shoes" examples) both sound strange, but this particular question probably *depends* on personal preference and maybe even the region where you live. I wonder if it is ever mentioned in grammar books.

Comment: @It'saboutEnglish With 'peed in' it's a very literal action of, pardon the brazen imagery, directing the stream towards the object. With no preposition, it's like you only altered the object. 'peed in the knitting' evokes there's some knitting on the floor and you're standing over it and... so on. 'peed the knitting' sounds like you're wearing the knitting. Which is weird for other reasons... because knitting is not particularly comfortable for underwear.

Comment: Personally, while it's certainly informal, I don't find the expression *peed X* to sound unnatural. No matter what the object is, dropping the preposition sounds okay to me. So, I would not mark your final two examples with a definitive **No** as you did in your answer. Perhaps qualify it with a person's particular dialect or region. Then again, I would also say that prepositions should always be used in formal writing. (The issue of using *peed* rather than *urinated* aside.)

Comment: I agree with the knitting. Pee your pants etc. but pee on things otherwise. A dog pees on a rock, just like a man might pee on the toilet seat. I thought this answer was completely to the point. The usage "peed his pants" or "peed himself" is not all that old.